# Compiler gives error: "Does not name a type" immediately after declared

Tags: c++, class, ncurses

I have a block of code from my project to build a c++ roguelike with ncurses. I am trying to make it so that the player can hold two weapons. i have created a weaponItem class and two objects, but the compiler still throws a 'does not name a type' error.

Code:

```
weaponItem weapon1;
weaponItem weapon2;

weapon1.setType(DMW_DAGGER);
weapon2.setType(DMW_SBOW);

weapon1.setPrefix(DMWP_AVERAGE);
weapon2.setPrefix(DMWP_RUSTY);
```

Compiler Error:

```
In file included from main.cpp:2:0:
hero.h:17:2: error: ‘weapon1’ does not name a type
  weapon1.setType(DMW_DAGGER);
  ^
hero.h:18:2: error: ‘weapon2’ does not name a type
  weapon2.setType(DMW_SBOW);
  ^
hero.h:20:2: error: ‘weapon1’ does not name a type
  weapon1.setPrefix(DMWP_AVERAGE);
  ^
hero.h:21:2: error: ‘weapon2’ does not name a type
  weapon2.setPrefix(DMWP_RUSTY); 
  ^
```

Is there something wrong with my class or object declaration?

Comment: You can't execute code at namespace scope like that.

Comment: weaponItem type is declared inside another header file which i have included at the top of the file i've shown.

Comment: You can't put executable code (like `weapon1.setType(DMW_DAGGER);`) by itself in a header file. Executable code in C++ must be within a function.

Comment: @MasonWatmough please include that header. Also force rebuild (just for good measure). This may be a namespace issue.

Comment: Allow me to explain further: DMW_* and DMWP_* are simply #define macros i have put in the same file. they are not functions.

Comment: Here's a link to the weaponItem header file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1j1lbKWU98ibjhiOFhaWTFHT2s/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Okay, i figured out that i needed to put it into a function. But i still have to ask why one has to execute a class function inside another function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding the error message and some of the comments.

Say you have a class/struct.

```
struct Foo
{
   Foo() : a(0) {}
   void set(int in) { a = 10; }
   int a;
};
```

You can define objects of type `Foo` outside function definitions.

```
// OK
Foo foo1;
```

However, you cannot call a member function of the class outside function definition by itself.

```
// Not OK in namespace scope or global scope.
foo1.set(20);
```

You can make function call inside a function definition in the file.

```
// OK.
void testFoo()
{
   foo1.set(20);
}
```

You can call a member function outside function definitions if you use its return value to initialize another variable.

```
struct Foo
{
   Foo() : a(0) {}
   void set(int in) { a = 10; }
   int get() { return a; }
   int a;
};

// OK
Foo foo1;
int x = foo1.get();
```

Comment: This clears up a lot. I forgot i was trying to execute code outside of the main function. Thanks for explaining it, but i still have to ask why my function must be nested inside another?